# How do I break apart items in a line of text when there may not be space between some terms?

Tags: regex, string, matlab, scientific-notation

In MATLAB, I have a block of text that I need to split apart. This is an example of such text:

```
ROW  SHORT-NAME             TYPE y1             y2             yRef           eq_lhs         eq_rhs         eq_ref         errorCon       tolerance      isConverged
1    CmpFan.S_Qhx.integ_TmatI    +6.3631e+002   +0.0000e+000   +6.3631e+002   TgasPath       Tmat           TgasPath       +1.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY1I1
2    CmpL.S_Qhx.integ_Tmat I    +8.0865e+002   +0.0000e+000   +8.0865e+002   TgasPath       Tmat           TgasPath       +1.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY2I1
3    CmpH.S_Qhx.integ_Tmat I    +1.2874e+003   +0.0000e+000   +1.2874e+003   TgasPath       Tmat           TgasPath       +1.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY3I1
4    BrnPri.S_Qhx.integ_TmatI    +2.8494e+003   +0.0000e+000   +2.8494e+003   TgasPath       Tmat           TgasPath       +1.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY4I1
5    TrbH.S_Qhx.integ_Tmat I    +3.3983e+003   +0.0000e+000   +3.3983e+003   TgasPath       Tmat           TgasPath       +1.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY5I1
6    TrbL.S_Qhx.integ_Tmat I    +2.6320e+003   +0.0000e+000   +2.6320e+003   TgasPath       Tmat           TgasPath       +1.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY6I1
7    BrnAug.S_Qhx.integ_TmatI    +1.6385e+003   +0.0000e+000   +1.6385e+003   TgasPath       Tmat           TgasPath       +1.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY7I1
8    dep_FanCustomerBleed  D    +0.0000e+000   +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-001   CmpFan.CbldAPTMS.WbldFanBleed       0.1            +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-002   TRUE      DY8I1
9    dep_LPCCustomerBleed  D    +0.0000e+000   +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-001   CmpL.CbldAPTMS.WbldLPCbleed       0.1            +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-002   TRUE      DY9I1
10   dep_HPCCustomerBleed  D    +3.0000e+000   +3.0000e+000   +1.0000e-001   CmpH.CbldAPTMS.WbldHPCbleed       0.1            +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-002   TRUE      DY10I1
11   dep_HPCCustomerBleedMidD    +0.0000e+000   +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-001   CmpH.CbldAPTMSmid.WbldHPCmidBleed    0.1            +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-002   TRUE      DY11I1
12   dep_HPXhigh           D    +2.0000e+002   +2.0000e+002   +2.0000e+002   ShH.HPX        HPXhigh        HPXhigh        +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   TRUE      DY12I1
13   dep_HPXlow            D    +5.0000e+002   +5.0000e+002   +5.0000e+002   ShL.HPX        HPXlow         HPXlow         +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   TRUE      DY13I1
14   FlowControl.dep_Tt    D    +8.6941e+002   +9.2300e+002   +9.2300e+002   Fl_I.Tt        Fl_O.Tt        FlowControl.Fl_O.Tt-5.8056e-002   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY14I1
15   FlowControl.dep_Pt    D    +7.0096e+001   +8.5000e+001   +8.5000e+001   Fl_I.Pt        Fl_O.Pt        FlowControl.Fl_O.Pt-1.7534e-001   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY15I1
16   FlowControl.dep_W     D    +8.0000e-002   +5.4000e-001   +5.4000e-001   Fl_I.W         Fl_O.W         FlowControl.Fl_O.W-8.5185e-001   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY16I1
17   MoveCCA.dep_Tt        D    +1.7141e+003   +1.7310e+003   +1.7310e+003   Fl_I.Tt        Fl_O.Tt        MoveCCA.Fl_O.Tt-9.7494e-003   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY17I1
18   MoveCCA.dep_Pt        D    +7.0096e+002   +6.9900e+002   +6.9900e+002   Fl_I.Pt        Fl_O.Pt        MoveCCA.Fl_O.Pt+2.8001e-003   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY18I1
19   MoveCCA.dep_W         D    +3.4000e+001   +2.2000e+001   +2.2000e+001   Fl_I.W         Fl_O.W         MoveCCA.Fl_O.W +5.4545e-001   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY19I1
20   dep_CCAflow           D    +3.4000e+001   +3.4000e+001   +3.4000e+001   CmpH.B_CCA.WbldCCAflow        CCAflow        +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   TRUE      DY20I1
21   ShH.integrate_Nmech   I    -2.6321e+003   +0.0000e+000   +2.4194e+004   trqNet         0.0000         trqIn          -1.0879e-001   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY21I1
22   ShL.integrate_Nmech   I    -5.1547e+003   +0.0000e+000   +3.0562e+004   trqNet         0.0000         trqIn          -1.6866e-001   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY22I1
23   DESIGN_OPR            D    +5.0176e+001   +5.0000e+001   +5.0000e+001   Overall_PR     D_OPR          50.0           +3.5200e-003   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY23I1
24   DESIGN_T41            D    +3.7465e+003   +3.5500e+003   +3.8000e+003   TrbH.Fl_I.Tt   D_T41          3800.0         +5.1708e-002   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY24I1
25   DESIGN_CombinedFanPR  D    +5.1200e+000   +4.9000e+000   +5.0000e+001   CmpFan.PR*CmpL.PRD_FANPR        50.0           +4.4000e-003   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY25I1
26   DESIGN_ThirdStreamFlowD    +9.9099e-002   +9.2500e-002   +1.3000e-001   ThirdStreamFlowD_ThirdStreamFlow0.13           +5.0762e-002   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY26I1
27   DESIGN_RMIX           D    +8.2279e-001   +1.0500e+000   +1.0500e+000   Mixer.RMIX     D_RMIX         1.05           -2.1639e-001   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY27I1
28   DESIGN_Wc             D    +4.2158e+002   +4.2500e+002   +4.0000e+002   CmpFan.Fl_I.Wc D_WAC          400.0          -8.5534e-003   +1.0000e-004   FALSE     DY28I1
```

Each line has the same type of information in it, but unfortunately the way it is produced, there is not necessarily space between terms. When this happens, it becomes difficult/impossible to know where to split terms. I would be OK with losing some of the string information columns in the middle, but I still need to be able to get the numbers somehow.

For rows like 13 where things are nicely spaced, something like the following works nicely (where one line is stored in the variable "txt"):

```
>>asCells = textscan(txt,'%d %s %c %f %f %f %s %s %s %f %f %s %s');
>> depTxt  = asCells{2}{1}
depTxt =
    'dep_HPXlow'
>> type    = asCells{3}
type =
    'D'
>> y1      = asCells{4}
y1 =
   500
>> y2      = asCells{5}
y2 =
   500
>> yRef    = asCells{6}
yRef =
   500
>> lhsTxt  = asCells{7}{1}
lhsTxt =
    'ShL.HPX'
>> rhsTxt  = asCells{8}{1}
rhsTxt =
    'HPXlow'
>> depTxt  = asCells{9}{1}
depTxt =
    'HPXlow'
>> err     = asCells{10}
err =
     0
>> tol     = asCells{11}
tol =
                    0.0001
>> if strncmp('TRUE',asCells{12}{1},4), conv = 1, else, conv = 0, end
conv =
     1
```

For something like row 11 that doesn't work at all since the first string and the character run together, throwing off the format string. Similarly, there is no way that it could know that the "CmpH.CbldAPTMSmid.WbldHPCmidBleed" piece should be broken up into "CmpH.CbldAPTMSmid.Wbld" and "HPCmidBleed". I'd be OK losing the eq_lhs, eq_rhs, and eq_ref info if there was a way to still get the numbered items and convergence flag later on, but that's where I'm struggling.

I can grab the first string (which I do need to keep) like this:

```
asCells = textscan(txt,'%d %s',1);
>> depTxt  = asCells{2}{1}
depTxt =
    'dep_HPCCustomerBleedMidD'
```

But I am not sure how to conditionally strip off the last character based on whether it ran into the TYPE column or not.

I noticed that all the actual numbers have a leading plus or minus and are in scientific notation (the numbers in the eq_ref column are really strings in this case). So I tried to use regexp to grab the numeric values like this:

```
>> asCells=regexp(txt,'[+-]\d+\.?\d*([eE][+-]?\d+)?','match','forceCellOutput');
>> y1      = str2double(asCells{1}{1})
y1 =
     0
>> y2      = str2double(asCells{1}{2})
y2 =
     0
>> yRef    = str2double(asCells{1}{3})
yRef =
                       0.1
>> err     = str2double(asCells{1}{4})
err =
     0
>> tol     = str2double(asCells{1}{5})
tol =
                      0.01
```

That seems to work OK, but I have no idea how to combine that with grabbing that string up front (especially with the need to conditionally strip off the I or D TYPE character). I'm also not sure how to get the convergence flag when it's not consistent which term it would be in the row based on the spacing. Can I regex search for the string TRUE or FALSE on each line? I think I'm close, but I'm struggling as to how to put all the pieces together.

Comment: Can't you just edit this text in another language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that gets you everything except `eq_lhs`, `eq_rhs`, and `eq_ref`. Had to do 2 passes of the regex because I couldn't capture `TYPE` from inside a lookahead expression for the first pass (maybe its possible but I don't quite know how...).

```
% load data from txt file
fptr = fopen('myData.txt');
s = fread(fptr, inf, 'uint8=>char');
fclose(fptr);
s = s';

% expressions w/named tokens
exprVarType = '(I|D)(?=\s+[+-])';
exprLineStart = '(?<row>\d+)\s+(?<shortName>[^\s]+(?=(\s*I|\s*D|(\s+(I|D)))))+[^+-]+';
exprSciNot1 = '(?<y1>[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)';
exprSciNot2 = '(?<y2>[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)';
exprSciNot3 = '(?<yref>[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)';
exprSciNot4 = '(?<errorCon>[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)';
exprSciNot5 = '(?<tolerance>[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)';

% concatenate regexs
myExpr = strcat(exprLineStart, exprSciNot1, '\s+', exprSciNot2,...
    '\s+', exprSciNot3, '[^+-]+', exprSciNot4, '\s+', exprSciNot5, '\s+',...
    '(\w+)', '\s+', '([^\r\n]+)');

% first pass: collect all variables except
% 3. Type
% 7. eq_lhs
% 8. eq_rhs
% 9. eq_ref
myData = regexp(s, myExpr, 'names');

% second pass: collect variable type
% couldnt capture this on the first pass because its part of a lookahead
% expression
varType = regexp(s, exprVarType, 'match');
% assign varType to the myData struct
[myData.varType] = deal(varType{:});
```

Comment: In trying to use your code, I realized that another valid TYPE is C (I think that's the only other one). Just a quick change to the exprVarType  and exprLineStart did the trick. Then I also added a couple lines to turn the numbers into number fields in the structure rather than character array fields. Thank you!

Comment: I hit a new snag trying now. In a different block of text in the same kind of file, the code didn't properly handle this line:

`31   dep_mixer_total_area    D    +1.0738e+003   +1.0738e+003   +1.0738e+003   Mixer.Fl_I1.Aphy + Mixer.Fl_I2.AphyMixer.areaMixedDP_MIXEDAREA   +0.0000e+000   +1.0000e-004   TRUE      DY31I1`

It's because of the plus sign in the middle of the eq_lhs expression. Any suggestions on how to make an adjustment for this kind of case? I'm thinking it would have to be something like detecting a non-numeric character after the plus (and potentially whitespace).

Comment: I think the issue is the expression `[^+-]+` I'll think about what other placeholder can go in there for the middle 3 columns and get back to you soon!